# What's the difference between viewBinding enabled true and buildfeatures viewBinding true

Tags: kotlin, groovy, android-viewbinding

What's the difference between the options to enable viewBinding:

```
viewBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

AND

Groovy

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

Kotlin

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

this used to be used and now some users are seeing error

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
}
```

they are using this.
But there is no difference in terms of usage.

Answer (score 2):

It is about AGP ( Android Gradle Plugin)
if you use old version AGP 3.6 and lower you should use viewBinding
{ enabled = true }:

if u use high version use buildFeatures { viewBinding = true }: